# Javascript: Textarea to html, how to save exact whitespaces count in html?

Tags: javascript, html

How to save exact whitespace count between words from textarea when putting it's value into html?

```
<textarea>word "10 whitespaces here" word "20 whitespaces here" word</textarea>
```

html:

```
<div style="width:50px;overflow:hidden;">word "10 whitespaces here" word "20 whitespaces here" word</div>
```

So that all text inside div would be visible.

Comment: you want to count the number of whitespace within the textarea right?

Comment: You must have a tiny font-size, to fit 20 spaces in 50px...

Comment: Omg guys you continue to amaze me. It's just as an example, so that everyone understand what i want. :)

Comment: Btw i have heard, that this is fixed in HTML5, but i need at least IE7 support of this, i'm not even talkin about IE6...

Comment: i still do not understand what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are creating your div from scratch, here is a way to replace the spaces with the HTML-friendly `&nbsp;`.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
// the below replaces two spaces with "&nbsp; "
newDiv.innerHTML = value.replace(/  /g, " &nbsp;");
```

Comment: "So that all text inside div would be visible." <c> Beck Mate there is div with 50px width and it have overflow:hidden. If you will replace whitespaces with nonbreaking character it will be unbreakable and most of it's part will not be visible.

Comment: Heh interesting solution :) and it's working indeed. It seems i have overworked today if have missed so simple solution :D. Only replacement should be like that " &nbsp;" , whitespace in front of &nbsp; because if between words is odd number of whitespaces, then two last whitespaces will be converted into one whitespace after they are put into html. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS property `white-space: pre` or replace spaces with `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Btw i have found this information here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html and it seems it is supported by IE6 and IE7. I'll check that out in a min. :)

Comment: Nope it's not working even in IE8 with compatibility mode. But it's working in Chrome and FF.